# modelo ApplicationUser no aparece en el listado 'Model class'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

cuando intento crear un controlador nuevo utilizando un 'Controlador con vista y usando Entity Framework' este modelo en particular no aparece dentro, lo que me hace preguntarme: por qué no aparecería una clase en este listado?

Por favor ayúdenme con esto

Mi data context class está seleccionada, pero aún asi no carga la clase ApplicationUser.cs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: dale un re-build

Comment: ya lo hice hermano  :(

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema y a un no encuentro la solución. Por favor si me pudieran ayudar.

Comment: Clean y rebuild la solución entera.

Comment: Este workshop te ayudará a entender mejor ASP.net MVC : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY